# Actionscript 3.0 Image Array

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a game and I want an array to store the images that I want displayed. I'm a bit confused regarding the images in the array, I don't know if I'm meant to put the instance name or else the image name in the array. I'm confused about how do I store the answers also. I would need the array to link up with the answers.

This is my original array

```
var characterArray:Array = new Array(); 
characterArray[0] = ["boy__pirate.png", "girl__pirate.png" , "pig__.png"]; 
characterArray[1] = ["girl__pirate.png", "girl__pirate.png" ,"boy__pirate.png"]; 
characterArray[2] = ["girl__pirate.png", "girl__pirate.png", "boy__pirate.png"];
```

To get the answers linked up with the array would I need to do something like that?

```
var questionone:Array = new Array();
["boy__pirate.png","boy__pirate.png,"girl__pirate.png"] 
var answerone: [choice1]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are those images? Are they image files in a folder or are they in the Flash library? What does this have to do with answers? What answers are you talking about? Your question is very vague, please clarify what you want to do exactly.

Comment: The images are in the flash library. The array is the question, just wanted to know if I would create another array regarding the answers or how I would go about that

Comment: What are the linkage names of the images in the library?

Comment: They are pirateboy, pirategirl and pig

Comment: Did you place those symbols from the library onto the stage? If so, what instance names did you use?